# What is the suggested way to use template in Chrome content scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use several templates in a Chrome content script for `elements` I'm adding to matched pages.

Currently I'm storing these templates as `string` in the script, but I wonder if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr answer** -  Yes, you can store them in a `<script type="text/html">` tags or load them dynamically through ajax. Examples [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) (from KnockoutJS) and [here](http://underscorejs.org/#template). Store them in a file with the proper extension and use an empty tag with an id X, then `$("#X").load("/path/to/template", function() { renderX(); })`

Long answer with insightful thoughts, keep reading...

### Please make sure templates/views or related GUI components of your system are in separate files <sub>(Keep reading to know why)</sub>

As a front end engineer, I learned to keep layers as separate as possible; this helps your team to understand better your code and make it more maintainable. Separating your layers in modules and then assembling them through an "assembly" mechanism is probably one of the best practices in software engineering. Some of the benefits of this practice include:

- **Maintainability**: Multiple developers can browse and edit single parts of your code in order to create a more robust piece of software.
- **Readability**: With the amount of languages around, you can't expect everyone to understand all the syntax of these X or Y language; mixing languages in a single file is just one step to confusing your code reviewer and make him spend more time than needed.
- **Accessibility**: Take for instance, html, jade, haml, smarty, twig, erb or other template files. Those files should always be named with the proper extension in order to help code editors and IDE's to syntax highlight. A developer should only need to glance a folder to know what those files are supposed to do. A script or bot can come up with important information from just an extension.

By keeping views in separate files, other coders can view them and understand an important layer of the system without needing to understand the entire application; even collaboration gets easier when the developer just need to review those specifics files. Through bashing or scripting, even large architectural systems with thousand of "views" like files can be filtered in order to output just what needs to be reviewed.

*(By now I hope I convinced you into removing your string from your code and create a new file and it there, otherwise I really need to improve my writing skills)*

So, after we have moved our template to an external file, **what do we do next?**

#### A word on Javascript and Chrome-Extensions

Javascript doesn't have a default templating feature (heck, it doesn't even have a modular one, although some smart people are working on it for the ECMAScript Ed. 6, yay!), which means that we need to use a templating library for that. Let's assume you are using Mustache, Underscore template of something alike and thus using its library to render it.

Most of those templating engines use the infamous `eval`, which can provide a vulnerability to your code, which Chrome Extensions dislike, a lot. The Chrome Extension Dev Team even enforced a new version of the `manifest.json` file in order to forbid `eval`, and gave developers the choice to use [Sandboxing Pages](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval.html) in order to do so. Luckily for us, they decided to relax the policies a little bit and we can continue use it with a proper [CSP](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) definition in our `manifest.json`.

This means that we need to tackle two problems instead of only one: the "load the template" one and the "render the template in a way won't freak out the new incoming versions of CSP in case the Chrome Extension Dev team change their mind".

#### Load the template

Load the template, luckily, can be done through an XML HTTP Request through AJAX. Just point the url with the name of the file and you can receive the template as a string, which was probably your original set up. Here's an example that I do with KnokcoutJS:

```
 $("#aiesecTemplate").load('js/libs/aiesec/aiesecTemplate.html', function() {
      ko.applyBindings(AIESECViewModel);
 });
```

The `#aiesecTemplate` is a `<script type="text/html">` tag that the browser won't render as part of the DOM. You can use that with other template mechanisms in order to actually assemble your DOM. If you have already a solution for this, this is probably the end of the answer and you can move on with your life. If you are wondering how do we render the code from there, keep reading.

#### Render the template

The Chrome Dev team suggest us to Sandbox our rendering process due most templating engine libraries being non-CSP compliant ([AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) being an exception). Here'an excerpt of the code from the Sandbox page.

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
```

Where `iframe` is a specific DOM Iframe Element from the sandbox page with a `src` attribute of a page that has the templating engine; `message` has the string template previously loaded,  so after posting the message a `window.addEventListener` for `message` inside the iframe can render it without a problem. More information about sandboxing eval can be read [here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval.html)

#### Conclusion

If you made it to here, awesome! My answers might not be that boring. As a last note, you might be thinking "What about AMD or RequireJS?"; to be honest I haven't tried them, but [really smart people](http://tomdale.net/2012/01/amd-is-not-the-answer/) think that AMD is not the best approach. Loading through a XML HTTP Request might not be better, but in case you think it hits your performance (I have used it in my application and it doesn't) you can always use some [Event Pages](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/event_pages.html)  and [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) with that.

Comment: Ummm, I don't think this answer is applicable to Chrome extensions?